# Laravel: How to count data in database?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make a list of students to know how many products each student buys. I have two tables : Member and Orders. In Orders table have column member_id and product_id. I want to count how many products each student buys. I can get list of student but i can't count how many products each student buys.

```php
    public function index()
        {
            $students = Member::getStudents();
            $order  = Order::where('member_id', $students->id)->count();
            return view('admin.student.index', compact('students'));
        }
```

But it appears an error:

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

function getStudents()

```php
     public static function getStudents()
        {
            $members = Member::where('member_type_id', BaseModel::$student)->get();
            for ($idxMember = 0; $idxMember < count($members); $idxMember++) { 
                if ( $members[$idxMember]->user_id ) {
                    $members[$idxMember]->username = User::find($members[$idxMember]->user_id)->username;
                }
            }
            return $members;
        }
```

Comment: You're trying to access the ID property of the Students collection:

`$students->id`

which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Looks like the issue is the `$students->id` where `id` does not exist. Try to print `$students` and check the id mark.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you get a collection on id.
so you should foreach your collection and get specific ids.

```php
public function index() {
   $students = Member::getStudents();
    foreach($students as $student ) {
      $order  = Order::where('member_id', $student->id)->count();
    }

    return view('admin.student.index', compact('students'));     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use relationships in Database. It would be more easy and simple.

In orders table, there is a column called member_id which reference to id column in members table. (Keep attention to singular plural usage)

Refer [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) for foreign key design and implementation.

You need 2 models, Member and Order. You should define the relationship as below.

Since this is One To Many Relationship,

In Member Model,

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Member extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the orders for the member.
     */
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }
}

?>
```

In Order Model,

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the member that owns the order.
     */
    public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Member');
    }
}

?>
```

Now you can get order count per user using this code.

```
Member::find(MEMBER_ID)->orders->count();
```

This will return order count of the selected member.

Please refer the Laravel Documentation here.

[Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) | [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) | [One To Many (Inverse)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply using laravel relationship

In order to do this please follow below steps

1. First, create two relation in members model

   public function orders()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order', 'member_id', 'id);
   }

Then retrieve the students details with orders

```
public function getStudents()
{
   return Member::where('member_type_id', BaseModel::$student)->withCount('orders)->get();
}
```

Hope this helps

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing solution with explanation.

Objects are

- Member (Student is also a member. But the Type is different)
- Order (One order can have multiple products)
- Product (Product will allocate with Orders and Members can place Orders)

Now If you are using Laravel. So the best way is to use Eloquent Relationships.

**Model Member :**

1 Define [Query Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#query-scopes)

```
public function scopeStudents($query)
{
    return $query->where('member_type_id', 1);
}
```

2 Define [One to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#one-to-many) relation between Order and Member (One Student can have multiple orders. And I hope that other members can also have orders. So i am going to relate direct Member to Order)

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
}
```

and

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product', 'App\Order');
}
```

**Model Order :**

1 Define relation with Member Model for One to Many

```
public function member()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Member');
}
```

2 Define one to many between Order and Product

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

**Model Product :**

1 Define Order Product Relation

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
}
```

Now the Model work is done. Only data fetching is remaining. Tell me in comments if you think below code is less and useful and easy to understand.

**Controller Member :**

1 Index Function :

```
// this will fetch all students with their orders and products
$data = Member::students()->with('orders', 'products')->get();

// this will fetch all students with their orders and order's products
$data = Member::students()->with('orders.products')->get();

// this will fetch all students with their orders count and products count
$data = Member::students()->withCount('orders', 'products')->get();
```